# "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

Invalid attempt to read when no data is present ASP.NET

> Error is on line 46: `Dim requestid = dbreader.GetInt32(1)`

There's data in that column in my database so I'm stuck.

Can post more code if needed.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    writemystuff()
End Sub

Dim conn As New SqlConnection

Sub CloseDatabase()
    conn.Close()
End Sub

Sub ConnectToDatabase()
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbSQL").ConnectionString
    conn.Open()
End Sub


Sub writemystuff()

    'Response.Write(SQL1)

    Dim XMLOutput = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>"
    'XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<?xml-stylesheet type=""text/xsl"" href=""XMLSchema1.xslt""?>"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<requests "
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " xmlns = ""http://www.w3schools.com"""
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " xmlns:xsi = ""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"""
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " xsi:schemaLocation=""http://www.w3schools.com XMLSchema1.xsd"">"
    ConnectToDatabase()

    Dim choice = Request("requestchoice")
    Dim SQL1 = "select * from request where r_id = 314"
    If choice = "Request 112" Then
        SQL1 = "select * from request where r_id = 112"
    End If

    Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(SQL1, conn)
    Dim dbreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    For Each record In dbreader

    Next

    Dim requestid = dbreader.GetInt32(1)
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<vendor"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " v_name=""" & dbreader.GetString(2) & """"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " v_id=""" & dbreader.GetInt32(0) & """"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " r_id=""" & dbreader.GetInt32(1) & """"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " >"
    Dim SQL2 = "select * from product where r_id = " & requestid

    Dim cmd2 = New SqlCommand(SQL2, conn)

    Dim dbreader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
    For Each record2 In dbreader2
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<product"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_name=""" & dbreader2.GetString(3) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_id=""" & dbreader2.GetInt32(0) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " cost=""" & dbreader2.GetDecimal(2) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " >"

    Next
    dbreader2.Close()
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "</request>"

    CloseDatabase()
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "</requests>"
    Response.Write(XMLOutput)
End Sub
End Class
```

Updated code that still has issues:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    writemystuff()
End Sub

Dim conn As New SqlConnection

Sub CloseDatabase()
    conn.Close()
End Sub

Sub ConnectToDatabase()
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbSQL").ConnectionString
    conn.Open()
End Sub


Sub writemystuff()

    'Response.Write(SQL1)

    Dim XMLOutput = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>"
    'XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<?xml-stylesheet type=""text/xsl"" href=""XMLSchema1.xslt""?>"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<requests "
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " xmlns = ""http://www.w3schools.com"""
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " xmlns:xsi = ""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"""
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " xsi:schemaLocation=""http://www.w3schools.com XMLSchema1.xsd"">"
    ConnectToDatabase()

    Dim choice = Request("requestchoice")
    Dim SQL1 = "select * from request where r_id = 314"
    If choice = "Request 112" Then
        SQL1 = "select * from request where r_id = 112"
    End If

    Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(SQL1, conn)
    Dim dbreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    For Each record In dbreader


        While dbreader.Read()
            Dim requestid = dbreader.GetInt32(1)
            XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<vendor"
            XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " v_name=""" & dbreader.GetString(2) & """"
            XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " v_id=""" & dbreader.GetInt32(0) & """"
            XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " r_id=""" & dbreader.GetInt32(1) & """"
            XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " >"
            Dim SQL2 = "select * from product where r_id = " & requestid
        End While

        Dim cmd2 = New SqlCommand(SQL2, conn)

        Dim dbreader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
        While dbreader2.Read()
            XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<product"
            XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_name=""" & dbreader2.GetString(3) & """"
            XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_id=""" & dbreader2.GetInt32(0) & """"
            XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " cost=""" & dbreader2.GetDecimal(2) & """"
            XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " >"
        End While

    Next

    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "</request>"


    CloseDatabase()
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "</requests>"
    Response.Write(XMLOutput)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `.Read()` on the `SqlDataReader` object to get the data for the row, like this:

```
While dbreader2.Read()
    ' Do logic here to get individual values from each row
End While
```

UPDATE:

Instead of this:

```
Dim dbreader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
For Each record2 In dbreader2
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<product"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_name=""" & dbreader2.GetString(3) & """"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_id=""" & dbreader2.GetInt32(0) & """"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " cost=""" & dbreader2.GetDecimal(2) & """"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " >"

Next
```

Do this:

```
Dim dbreader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
While dbreader2.Read()
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<product"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_name=""" & dbreader2.GetString(3) & """"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_id=""" & dbreader2.GetInt32(0) & """"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " cost=""" & dbreader2.GetDecimal(2) & """"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " >"
End While
```

---

> Note: If you are interested in knowing if the `SqlDataReader` has any rows or not, then you can check that before looping through the reading of rows, like this:

```
Dim dbreader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
If dbreader2.HasRows Then
    While dbreader2.Read()
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<product"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_name=""" & dbreader2.GetString(3) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_id=""" & dbreader2.GetInt32(0) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " cost=""" & dbreader2.GetDecimal(2) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " >"
    End While
Else
    ' Potentially generate a "no data found" message here, etc.

End If
```

---

UPDATE 2:

Okay, here is what your full method code should look like:

```
Sub writemystuff()
    'Response.Write(SQL1)

    Dim XMLOutput = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>"
    'XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<?xml-stylesheet type=""text/xsl"" href=""XMLSchema1.xslt""?>"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<requests "
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " xmlns = ""http://www.w3schools.com"""
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " xmlns:xsi = ""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"""
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " xsi:schemaLocation=""http://www.w3schools.com XMLSchema1.xsd"">"
    ConnectToDatabase()

    Dim choice = Request("requestchoice")
    Dim SQL1 = "select * from request where r_id = 314"
    If choice = "Request 112" Then
        SQL1 = "select * from request where r_id = 112"
    End If

    Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(SQL1, conn)
    Dim dbreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim requestid As Integer
    While dbreader.Read()
        requestid = dbreader.GetInt32(1)
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<vendor"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " v_name=""" & dbreader.GetString(2) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " v_id=""" & dbreader.GetInt32(0) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " r_id=""" & dbreader.GetInt32(1) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " >"
    End While

    Dim SQL2 = "select * from product where r_id = " & requestid
    Dim cmd2 = New SqlCommand(SQL2, conn)
    Dim dbreader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
    While dbreader2.Read()
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<product"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_name=""" & dbreader2.GetString(3) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_id=""" & dbreader2.GetInt32(0) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " cost=""" & dbreader2.GetDecimal(2) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " >"
    End While
    dbreader2.Close()
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "</request>"

    CloseDatabase()
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "</requests>"
    Response.Write(XMLOutput)
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do i put my Dim SQL2?

Comment: @user2860150 - same place, do not change how you are retrieving the data, just change the way you are "reading" the data by using the `While dbreader2.Read()` syntax. You will use the same concept for `dbreader`, but that had an empty `For` loop in your posted code, so I decided to use the second reader (`dbreader2`) as the example, because it had logic in the loop.

Comment: It says SQL2 is not declared

Comment: @user2860150 - do you still have this line: `Dim SQL2 = "select * from product where r_id = " & requestid` in your code?

Comment: I've updated my code with your suggested changes. Any ideas? :/

Comment: @user2860150 - I have posted in `UPDATE 2:` the full code you should have in your `writemystuff()` method.

Comment: Okay thank you! That code fixed the errors. But.....it says Index was outside the bounds of the array on line 43:            requestid = dbreader.GetInt32(1)

Comment: Theres only 1 column in the request table

Comment: @user2860150 - that is your problem, `GetInt32()` is zero-based, so it should be `GetInt32(0)` instead of `GetInt32(1)`.

Comment: ok then it says the error is in XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " v_name=""" & dbreader.GetString(2) & """" but the weird thing is that v_name is in the 3rd column...

Comment: @user2860150 - if there is only one column in the `request` table, then there is no way that `.GetString(2)` would work, because the largest index for a single column is `0`. The `SELECT *` is returning one column, which is referenced by `GetInt32(0)`, right?

Comment: the `.GetString(2)` is supposed to be accessing data from my vendor table. Same with the next two GetInts

Comment: @user2860150 - the problem is that you are trying to read the vendor information which is not returned from the request table.

Comment: @user2860150 - where is your "vendor" query?

Comment: Would it be easier to post my xml?

Comment: @user2860150 - you need to create a third query for retrieving the vendor information (i.e. `SELECT * FROM vendor WHERE xyz = ???`).

Comment: I'm trying to allow you to choose one of two radio buttons in HTML and that will then pull the related data from my SQL database which has 3 tables, Request (Parent) and Vendor(child) and Product(child).

Comment: @user2860150 - well then you need to add the conditional logic (`if`) into your data access code to only put the vendor information in the XML output if the appropriate radio button is checked.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `Next` of the first DataReader too soon:

```
For Each record In dbreader
   ' Do Nothing
Next

' Reader is now at the end - can't read any more!
Dim requestid = dbreader.GetInt32(1)
```

But in reality you should use `Do While dbReader.Read()`:

```
Do While dbReader.Read()

    Dim requestid = dbreader.GetInt32(1)
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<vendor"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " v_name=""" & dbreader.GetString(2) & """"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " v_id=""" & dbreader.GetInt32(0) & """"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " r_id=""" & dbreader.GetInt32(1) & """"
    XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " >"

    Dim SQL2 = "select * from product where r_id = " & requestid

    Dim cmd2 = New SqlCommand(SQL2, conn)

    Dim dbreader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
    Do While dbReader2.Read()
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<product"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_name=""" & dbreader2.GetString(3) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_id=""" & dbreader2.GetInt32(0) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " cost=""" & dbreader2.GetDecimal(2) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " >"

    Loop
Loop
```

Comment: when i use this code i just get a white screen when I try and open in the browser

Comment: Check your XML in the debugger.  I don't see where you're closing off the `vendor` or `product` nodes, so your XML is not well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

DataReader is used to for reading a forward-only stream of rows from a SQL Server database. You need to call Read the next record.

On your code, you need to change this (e.g., you need to change it as it is supposed to work, don't copy paste, please)

```
 Dim dbreader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
    For Each record2 In dbreader2
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<product"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_name=""" & dbreader2.GetString(3) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_id=""" & dbreader2.GetInt32(0) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " cost=""" & dbreader2.GetDecimal(2) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " >"

 Next
```

for something like

```
 Dim dbreader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
 While  dbreader2.Read()
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + "<product"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_name=""" & dbreader2.GetString(3) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " p_id=""" & dbreader2.GetInt32(0) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " cost=""" & dbreader2.GetDecimal(2) & """"
        XMLOutput = XMLOutput + " >"

 End While
```

As you might imagine, your connection will still busy as long you are using the data reader. You should always be sure that you can close your data reader to close the connection and send it to pool again. This is one of the primary reasons of connection leak in .NET.

You can do it using the statement "using" you doing a try{} finally{} block (it's the same thing).